# Matlab read heterogenious binary data

Tags: matlab, pointers, memcpy, fread

I'd like to read heterogenious binary data into matlab. I do know from the beginning how much it is and in which datatype each segment is. For example:

```
%double %double %int32 ...
```

and then this get repeated about a million times. Easy enoug to handle with `fread` since the know the number of bites for each segment and can therefore calculate the skip value for each row.

But now the data segment looks something like this :

```
%double %int32%*char %double %double ...
```

Whereby the `int` prior to the `*char` is the length of the said string. This brings the problem that I cannot calculate the skip anymore and I'm stuck be reading in the whole file line by line therefore needing to make a lot more file access and slowing everthing down.

In order to get at least some speed up I wan't to read in all `%double %double ...` (Around 30 elements) at a time and then use those from a buffer to fill up the array's. In C this would be a rather easy task here, without memcpy and not so direct access to pointers...

Do you know any way to achive this, not using mex files?

Comment: I don't think there's a builtin function, that would understand "read as many chars as this int is telling you". With this "dynamical nature" of the format, I guess repeated freads is the only choice.

Comment: Another thought: If you have an impact on the format, you might think about storing the chars with fixed length, padding shorter char array with zeros if necessary. This only applies though if the char-arrays are all within a certain length...

Comment: @sebastian. Unfortunatly I do not have any control on that side. It is pretty much fixed as it is. Otherwise I would choose something like HDF5 and I would not have to deal with all these...

Comment: You can write Java commands in Matlab. Using these you should be able to use functions similar to the ones in C.

Comment: @bdecaf That't not really necessary - it probably won't get faster than using matlab's `fread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't solve the problem that the record size is unknown, and thus you don't know how much to read ahead of time.  But you *can* batch up the reads, and if you have a reasonable max size for the string, you can always read that amount, and ignore the unneeded bytes at the end.  `typecast` is the trick:

```
readlen = 1024;
buf = fread(fid, readlen, '*uint8');   % the asterisk keeps the returned array as uint8
rec.val1 = typecast(buf(1:8), 'double');
string_len = typecast(buf(9:12), 'int32');
rec.str1 = typecast(buf(13:13+string_len-1), 'uint8');

pos = 13+string_len;
rec.val2 = typecast(buf(pos:pos+8-1), 'double');
```

You might wrap a simple function around this technique to track the current offset automatically.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know that typecast existed in matlab. Thank you